# Display JSON response array in Phonegap

Tags: json, cordova

very quick question
i have webservice which returns JSON array

I want to display that JSON array in phonegap app

how can i do that
so far i was trying this
but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.jsonp({
    url: 'getevents.php',
    callbackParameter: 'callback',
    success: function (data, status) {
        //$('#your-tweets').append('<li>The feed loads fine');
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var tweet = item.title;
            $('#your-tweets').append('<li>' + tweet);
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#your-tweets').append('<li>There was an error loading the feed');
    }
});
```

});

And here is my `index.html` file

```
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="your-tweets"></ul>
</body>
```

But with this code i am getting error that `$.jsonp is not a function`

If there are some tutorials available online than do provide me the link as well

I have tried this function as well
But somehow i cannot figure out where to pass the return array from the webservice

```
function readJSONData() {
$.getJSON("getevents.php",function(data){
    if(data) {
    var json_data;
    $('#read-data').hide();
    $('.demo-table').show();
    $.each(data, function(i,event){
    json_data = '<tr>'+
        '<td valign="top">'+
        '<div class="feed_title">'+event.title+'</div>'+
        '<div>'+event.description+'</div>'+
        '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
    $(json_data).appendTo('#demo-table-content');
    });
    } else {
    json_data += '<tr>'+
        '<td valign="top">No Tutorials Found</td>'+
        '</tr>';
    $(json_data).appendTo('#demo-table-content');
    }       
});
```

}

I can see in the firebug that on ajax request it returns the `event` array but on the page i get `undefined` instead of the data

thank you and really appreciate it

Comment: please share code on jsFiddle, I will help you to sort it out

Comment: @sunil [jsDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/a0ox6cnt) here is the link and you can go to the web service i am using in there and see the array format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this prototype. And not event is an array so you have to check element in array i.e. `data.event[index]`

also you don't have any parameter data.event.desc so referring to that element will result `undefined`.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <a href="#" id="getdata-button">Get JSON Data</a>
    <div id="showdata"></div>
    </body>
    </html> 



    $(document).ready(function(){ 
            //attach a jQuery live event to the button
            $('#getdata-button').live('click', function(){
                $.getJSON('http://dev.app.horsebuzz.com/dbconnection/getevents.php', function(data) {   
                    //alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
                    //alert (data.item1+" "+data.item2+" "+data.item3); //further debug      
                    for(var i=0;i<data.event.length;i++){
                    $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+data.event[i].title+" item2="+data.event[i].start_date+" item3="+data.event[i].location+"</p>");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: also add Jquery and Jquery mobile js files first

Comment: Thats perfect.. Sorry for late replay but thank you for helping me for this... appreciate it